# Can overly permissive CORS settings lead to CSRF?

Tags: cors, csrf, same-origin-policy

I feel like anytime I see documentation on CORS it's recommending to just have a default `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` configuration. It seems to me this is a perfect way to make your API now vulnerable to CSRF attacks. The explanation being that Same Origin Policy is the only thing stopping XHR requests in the browser from making API endpoints completely vulnerable to CSRF, and that CORS is essentially a bypass for SOP.

Is my logic sound that any site with an overly permissive CORS settings is essentially exposing their backend API to CSRF attacks? If so, then this should be explicitly mentioned anytime CORS is brought up.

Answer (score 0):

Allowing all origins is certainly not best practice but this doesn't necessarily subject you to CSRF unless you're allowing cookies on the incoming requests.  To mitigate CSRF you'll want to:

1. Validate the origin.  Typically you define a whitelist in code or configuration.  If the incoming origin isn't in the whitelist, reject the request with a 403 status code.
2. Add anti-CSRF support via tokens.  Microsoft has a good [article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks) on their use in ASP.NET MVC and Web API.  Basically the token is just a random string that changes on each request.

Also consider using something other than cookies to authenticate the request/user.  For example, consider the use of authentication tokens submitted via the Authorization header.

One resource I highly recommend to learn more about CORS and mitigating CSRF is the book [CORS In Action](https://www.manning.com/books/cors-in-action) by Monsur Hossain.  The author's also created a good companion website (enable-cors.org) with samples and links to additional resources.